# Need help resolving an error that says, no row at position 0

Tags: c#, database, select, datagridview, runtime-error

I am working on a c# project and in this project, I want to select some data and show in a datagridview but I have data in my database and I have a query of select but when I click the button so I get this type of error this no row at position 0

Here are the screenshots

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkNhg.jpg
- https://imgur.com/aeq0weF
- https://imgur.com/8AG3LZ4

Here is my code

```
dataGridView4.Columns.Add("", "Leave Consumed");
dataGridView4.Columns.Add("", "Leave Allaowed");
dataGridView4.Columns.Add("", "Balance");

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataSet ds1211122 = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt1211122 = new DataTable();
    ds1211122.Tables.Add(dt1211122);

    OleDbDataAdapter da1211122 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    da1211122 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Sum(USERID) FROM [CHECKINOUT] where " + 
        "[CHECKTYPE]= '" + "I" + "'AND [USERID] = " + 
        dataGridView4.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "AND [CHECKTIME] Between #" + 
        dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "# AND #" + 
        dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "# Group By [USERID];", VCON);

    da1211122.Fill(dt1211122);

    int num = 0;
    num = Convert.ToInt32(dt1211122.Rows[0][0].ToString());
    VCON.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please read up on the subject and use parameterized queries.

Comment: Obviously, the line of code…. `da1211122.Fill(dt1211122);` … is not filling a `DataTable` with rows. It would be prudent to “check” that the `DataTable` actually HAS rows after the “fill” and before you try to grab a value from one of the rows.